# vhdl compare new input with old input

Tags: input, store, vhdl

how do you do it?

I am very new to this and I am sure this is easy enough but i can't seem to figure out how

here is some pseudo code

```
port(x,y: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) -- 3 bit input that is basically counted eg ("000", "001", "010"... "111", "000" ...)
    q_out : out integer); -- this is just an example

signal temp_q_out: integer;

when x (or y) increments -- THIS IS THE PART I CAN'T GET
    temp_q_out <= temp_ q_out + 1;


case temp_q_out is
    when 0 q_out <= 7
    when 1 q_out <= 12
    when 2 q_out <= 4
    when others q_out <= 100
```

How do I make my temp_q_out count only when x or y increments and at no other time? I want my output q_out to be constantly 7 until x or y changes then be 12 till x or y changes again then be 2. What usually happens is that the output becomes 100 straight away.

Any help at all will be appreciated

Cheers Guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a safe way to do what you want with asynchronous logic. Assuming you want to synthesize this, you need a clock input. Then, you can add a process that stores the previous values of `x` and `y`, and checks whether the new value is equal to the old value or not. Here's an example:

```
process(clk)
  variable prev_x, prev_y : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if (x /= prev_x) or (y /= prev_y) then
      temp_q_out <= temp_q_out + 1;
    end if;
    prev_x := x;
    prev_y := y;
  end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use processes. Processes are executed like atomic statements. You can use variables inside them. The following process listens on the x and y signals. When one of them changes, the process is executed sequentially.

```
process(x, y)
variable tmpX: integer := -1;
variable tmpY: integer := -1;
begin
    if (x = tmpX + 1) or (y = tmpY + 1) then
        temp_q_out <= temp_ q_out + 1;
    tmpX := x;
    tmpY := y;
end process;
```

The first execution of the process depends on your specific case, so modify the "-1" value as you please.

Comment: This is OK if it's not for synthesis, otherwise I would definitely not do this. It will result in latches and be prone to glitches, and I doubt it will work as expected.